# Show relative time that changes to default date after Midnight

Tags: php

I would like to show "posted Today at" if the posted was posted today, and I know how to do that, but I would like it to show the default date and time format as of 12:01am, obviously because ita no longer posted "today", is there a way I can do this? Thanks for the help.

---

Thanks, I'll try that, here is what i have.

```
if($params['time'] > (time() - (60*60*24))){

$old_time = $params['time'];

$hm = date("g:ia", $old_time);

$today = elgg_echo('friendly_time_today', array($hm));

return $today;

    return $today;

  } else if($params['time'] > (time() - (60*60*48))){

$old_time = $params['time'];

$hm = date("g:ia", $old_time);

$yesturday = elgg_echo('friendly_time_yesturday', array($hm));

return $yesturday;

    return $yesturday; }
```

Comment: post code showing what you already tried, or where you want this functionality to be added...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
<?php
$sSaved = "11:08am 01.01.2012"; // comes from date("H:ia d.m.Y");
$aSaved = explode(" ", $sSaved);
if ($aSaved[1] != date("d.m.Y")) {
    echo $sSaved;
} else {
    echo "today";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly, this might make sense somehow:

```php
# example function
function stylePostDateExample (DateTime $postDate) {
    # get current date
    $currDate = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    # grab the interval between the post date and current date
    $intervalObj = date_diff($postDate, $currDate);

    # simple output start
    $stringOut = "Posted ";

    # interpret difference
    if ($intervalObj->format('%d') < 1 && $intervalObj->format('%y%m') == 0){
        # still within the day
        $stringOut .= "today at " . $intervalObj->format('%H:%I');
    } else {
        # the post date day has passed
        $stringOut .= "on " . date_format($postDate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    return $stringOut;
}

# test: any previous day
$postDate = date_create('2012-01-01 00:00:00');
echo stylePostDateExample ($postDate);

# results
# -----------------------------------------
# Posted on <date value here>

# test: today
$postDate = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
echo stylePostDateExample ($postDate);

# results
# -----------------------------------------
# Posted today at <time value here>
```

The function requires a datetime value which I suppose you get from the database (for the post's date of creation/posting) and it outputs a string as presented.

If I'm missing the point, please let me know.